# How to update records in a database through the VB CodeBehind file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, sql-update, code-behind

I am creating a website where users are able to update their personal details on a web form once they click the update button. I was able to create the code needed to add users to the database, which I have included. I have been working on Visual Studios and placed this code in the CodeBehind file of a button. So I was wondering if there was a similar way I could use an Update clause to update the table data.

[image: Add new user code]

Comment: Please attach written code instead of an image (indent with 4 spaces to form a code block)

Answer (score 0):

Under the function of btn_Update (for example), do the same thing like you insert the data. Just change the INSERT SQL Statement to UPDATE for example

```
Dim cmdstring as string = " UPDATE Engineers SET column1 = newvalue1, column2 = new value2 WHERE userID = selectedUserID
```

I really suggest you the make a unique ID in the table for you to easily any unique ID to replace with the new data like in the code it uses WHERE clause is to find which row to replace with the new value. FirstName is still not unique if there's 2 person with the same name. Try query the `index`.

Make sure u make any checkbox/dropdown/selection method to choose which row to replace with the new data.